# ZH960 tablet, suspicious hardware parameters, what to do?

Tags: tablet

I've bought a recent, middle (or top) category Android tablet model ZH960. It specification says 8GB RAM and 128GB flash, with an astonishing 1280x2560 display.

However, after I've tried it, it simply did not work so. It is slow (particularly using recent browsers), the display resolution is clearly worse than specified (pixels are well visible), contrary that the "Settings" -> "About this tablet" says the values specified by the reseller.

What to do? How to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fake.

Probably the "producer" bought tablet with 1 GB RAMs, and flashed them with a firmware lying about their hardware. However, some simple adb shell commands show the real hardware capacity:

[image]

Fact is that the device has 1GB RAM and a 16GB flash. It is today a low-end device, overwritten by a firmware which falsify the reported hw parameters.

The internet is full with

- Unclear / contradicting "specifications" of this hardware.
- Warnings about the scam ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ayu4NKaZvA4)).

I could not find any trace of the producer. Most likely, the model does not even exist.

If you bought this table, here is the time to initiate a customer complain. If you can not, my sincere condolences.

Comment: Side note: I bought this thing on ebay. The seller paid my money back, but wanted the fake device back. I sent it back to him. And then... he simply sold it to others! I tried to report the cheat to the ebay, but nothing happened! Their reporting page does not even have a cheat/fake option!